# What means remote=. in GIT config?

Tags: git

I'm not sure how (branch created with EGit, probably) I ended with this section in my config:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "sfc"]
    remote = .
    merge = refs/heads/master
    rebase = true
```

I would like to understand this. I'm not sure if the dot in `remote = .` is interpreted as url (current directory) or a special repository name (alias to myself)? Is that legal/normal/typical, or should I guess that this is messed up? It look strange to me to have a "remote" spec that points to the same repository. Furthermore, that branch indeed exists in the remote... What would be the implicancies of this regarding push/pull behaviour?

Some more info:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://git@10.0.0.3/var/gitrep/zzz.git
  Push  URL: ssh://git@10.0.0.3/var/gitrep/zzz.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master tracked
    sfc    tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
    sfc    pushes to sfc    (up to date)

$ git branch -vv
* master     f394d8b [origin/master: ahead 1] Bla blah...
  sfc        8065309 [master: behind 89] Bla blah...
```

Comment: I think it references your current repository... try to create a commit and do ``git fetch sfc``?

Answer (score 4):

That is quite strange. I went ahead and created a dummy repo, changed `.git/config` to make a remote be `.`, added some code, committed, and pushed.

```
$ git checkout weird
$ touch nothing
$ git add nothing
$ git commit -a -m "test"
[sup 031541e] test
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 nothing
$ git push
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push . HEAD:master

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

git push . weird

$ git push . weird
Everything up-to-date
```

It appears to be hitting the repository locally, which of course means that a push results in git saying it's up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Git will resolve this as a relative path, just like `../../some/other/repo`. As such it will resolve the directory of the repository itself. As your remote merge target is `master`, running `git push` while `sfc` is checked out, will simply try to fast-forward `master` to `sfc`.

You can create branches like that by running

```
git branch --set-upstream somebranch
```

Maybe that’s what you did, because you forgot to set a remote branch as starting point.